# Nodejs DocumentDB - deleteDocument

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to delete documents in a DocumentDB collection that have a certain field value (documentType='Virtual'). I'm doing a query document call before to get an array of docs found matching, and this worling fine. But when I call the .deleteDocument function.... nothing happens! No errors and it doesn't enter the callback code that I can see running in the debugger.
I'm using VS Community 2015.

I've looked both online at the documentation and Azure examples and can't figure out the problem so have posted here.

Any ideas?

```
console.log("Found " + results.length + " document(s) to delete");
for (r in results )
{
    var docId = results[r].id;
    docLink = 'dbs/' + databaseId + '/colls/' + collectionId + '/docs/' + docId;
    console.log(results[r]);
    client.deleteDocument(docLink , function (err) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            handleError(err);
        } 
        else 
        {
            console.log('Document deleted');
            delCount++;
        }
    });
}
console.log("Deleted " + delCnt + " document(s)");
```

Thanks

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, you console.log `delCnt` but you are incrementing `delCount`. That said, I don't think that's the biggest problem.

In JavaScript, you shouldn't put a call to an async operation into a loop because it will just make a ton of calls and overflow some resource (probably open connections) before the first one gets a chance to return.

Rather, you need to handle it in a way that's conducive to JavaScript's async nature. Two options:

1. **Recursively**. Something like this (untested).

   ```
   console.log("Found " + results.length + " document(s) to delete");
   delCount = 0;
   deleteDoc();

   function deleteDoc()
   {
       var doc = results.pop();
       var docId = doc.id;
       docLink = 'dbs/' + databaseId + '/colls/' + collectionId + '/docs/' + docId;
       client.deleteDocument(docLink , function (err) 
       {
           if (err) 
           {
               handleError(err);
           } 
           else 
           {
               console.log('Document deleted');
               delCount++;
               if (results.length > 0)
               {
                   deleteDoc();
               }
               else
               {
                   console.log("Deleted " + delCount + " document(s)");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Using an async parallelization library**. The downside to the above is that you won't get any parallelization meaning new calls to delete the next doc won't occur until the last one completes. To get around this, I recommend the use of a library like [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/). I recommend the [eachOfLimit()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfLimit) function for this need. You'll have to experiment with the parallelization limit, but start with 10 and go up from there until you either get the parallelization you want or you hit some resource limit. I can write out the code for using async.js if you decide to go that way, just ask in the comments.

Comment: HI Larry, Thanks for the comments, I will look into the async library as I've seen it mentioned elsewhere. Agree with you regarding the loop. TBH, one of the biggest problems I am having with documentDB is the lack of good solid documentation and examples for nodeJS, I have to say that MongoDB is way out in front and their APIs are far simpler to use. Surely deleting documents in a collection shouldn't be so hard in a document-oriented database?! Regards Gary.

Comment: Having used both extensively, I agree there is a difference in maturity of those two sets of docs. What I like the most about the DocumentDB docs is that they are all GitHub projects. My first submissions to DocumentDB were edits to those docs.

If you are able to get it to work based upon my suggestions can you please accept the answer?

Comment: After a bit of fiddling around I used async and got it to work via stream processing. Not an easy task to complete but once learnt, not forgotten!

Comment: Does stream processing parallelize the requests?